# Working with Routes in express js and socket.io and maybe node in general

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to write a multi channel application in socket.io. The channel you are in should be defined by the url you are on. If I do the joining part in the app.js with permanent values everything works. As soon as I change it so that the route for route.page does the joining I get the error, that sockets is not available in the context. What would be the correct way so that I can dynamically join the channel?

/app.js

```
var io = socketio.listen(app);
require('./io')(io);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {  
  socket.on('debug', function (message) {
    socket.get('channel', function (err, name) {
      socket.in(name).broadcast.emit('debug', message);
    });
  });
});
```

/io.js

```
var socketio = function (io) { 
  if (!io) return socketio._io;  
  socketio._io = io;
} 

module.exports = socketio;
```

/routes/index.js

```
var io = require('../io')();
exports.page = function(req, res){
  var channel = req.params.id;
  res.render('page', { title: 'PAGE', channel: channel  });
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.join(channel);
    socket.set('channel', channel );
  });
};
```

Comment: I'm probably confused, the way I read that is "I can't seem to get the client to initiate the socket from code in the route" which is obviously wrong. Can you help me clarify the issue so I can see it "more correctly" instead of the way I see it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to do multiple channels is off of different URLs.

For example I have the client do the following:

```
io.connect('/game/1')
io.connect('/system')
```

and on the server I have

```
io.of('/game/1').on('connect' function(socket) {...})
io.of('/system').on('connect' function(socket) {...})
```

It looks like I'm connecting twice here, but socket.io is smart enough to use a single websocket for this connection (at least it says so in the how-to-use).